# loading views dynamically using file_ids stored in a database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got a table which stores the file ids of the files on the server in the views folder>its is for a project where I allow the user to upload html files and see what the user has uploaded. Iwant to the load all the files using a single controller function
Here's what I am doing..

```
           public function site_pages()
          {
                 $this->load->model('model_site');
                 // a function which returns the name and file_ids in the database
                 $rows=$this->model_site->get_temp_sites();
                foreach ($rows as $r) 
                {$file_id=$rows->file_id;
                 $r->file_name=$this->uri->segment(3);  
                 $this->load->view('includes/header');
             $this->load->view('site_pages/'.$file_id,$user_data);
                 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
                 }

      }
```

However this shows two weboages nested in each other....How can I overcome this problem as well as load all the files using a single controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the cases where an iframe may actually be a good idea.  Your enclosing page can simply provide an iframe pointed at the URL for the HTML content page to be viewed.

I think the iframe makes sense here in that, I assume, you are trying to provide an unaltered view of the HTML content (i.e. not use enclosing page's CSS rules, javascript, etc.).

Comment: yeah, but I am processing the files a bit for security and thereafter loading the changed file_ids in the database. I cant understand how to load the pages iteratively using a single controller as I  am renaming the folders as well while upload.

Comment: @user1978166 I guess I didn't understand the question then. I thought your problem was about how to properly display one HTML page within another.